# APEXExport don't exported application with correct name

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-apex

I'm trying to export my apex applications with APEXExport class, but the sql file is always generated with the name "???" instead of "f"+application id+".sql". When I try to export all workspace applications it replace always the file "???" by latest exported application, so i can't have different application files.

Any ideas could help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, how exactly do you do that? I'm exporting Apex applications daily, no problem. Though, one-by-one.

Here's my MS Windows `.bat` script, see if it helps. It

- exports Apex applications
- creates ZIP file name by using `DATE` value so that I could keep daily backups
- ZIPs all exported .sql files
- deletes .sql files

---

```
@ECHO OFF

echo Export APEX applications

E:
cd E:\apex_4.2_instalacija\utilities

@ECHO ON

REM Archive
java oracle.apex.APEXExport -db db_serv:1521:orcl -user archive -password xyz -applicationid 126
REM Human resources
java oracle.apex.APEXExport -db db_serv:1521:orcl -user humres  -password xyz -applicationid 139
REM Etc. - list all applications you're exporting

@ECHO OFF

copy f????.sql E:\Apex_backup\f????_50_%date:~10,4%_%date:~7,2%_%date:~4,2%.sql
del f????.sql

E:
cd E:\Apex_backup

REM Today's date in YYYY_MM_DD format
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=. " %%i in ('date /t') do set yyyy_mm_dd=%%l_%%k_%%j

REM ZIP file name: APEX_YYYY_MM_DD.ZIP
set ime_zipa=apex_%yyyy_mm_dd%.zip

"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z" a -tzip %ime_zipa% E:\apex_backup\f*%yyyy_mm_dd%*.sql

dir %ime_zipa%

REM Delete exported .sql files
del f*%yyyy_mm_dd%*.sql
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I copied the utilities folder to a directory, in which I run the APEXExport class. Even when I export one by one it always creates a file with a name ???. I'm using APEX 19.2 what's your APEX version?

Comment: Apex I use is 18.2. Its applications are exported with APEXExport version 4.2. Why? because we had to change the database server, it is not accessible by us (in a way that we could perform export) so we use the "old" version installed on the old server which, apparently, works just fine.

Comment: I changed my APEXExport version for 5.0 and it work well, but no higher version works for me! Thanks.